# Buttons doesn't appear using Metaio Cloud plugin Metaio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, metaio

I am developing an App using cloud plugin to visualise a Junaio channel with Android Studio, on my xml file that contains the data of a my POIs, each of them has a routing button that should call a map app like google maps to route to the point, and another Button that should call a particular PHP script on my server. Then When I use Junaio App and scan the QR of the Channel i can see these buttons, but when i insert the channel number in Metaio cloud plugin Example, I can see just the POI, and after clicking each object, i can see the data but no buttons. How can i see these button also on the App i am developing.